# How to add no-argument constructor of inbuilt class for Firebase-database exception?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, constructor

I am trying to fetch the FirebaseLocationData object from Firebase Realtime 
Database in Android.

According to Docs, the class should have no arguments constructor which i have done as
`public FirebaseLocationData() {}` but it is still showing error

`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class android.location.Location does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.`

How am i supposed to make a **no-argument constructor** of **android.location.Location** class?

Error is produced by this line `FirebaseLocationData fld = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseLocationData.class);`

**code:**

```
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            FirebaseLocationData fld = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseLocationData.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fld.getEmail()+" added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

**FirebaseLocationData class:**

```
public class FirebaseLocationData {
String email;
Location location;
String time;

public FirebaseLocationData() {
}

public FirebaseLocationData(Location location, String email, String time) {
    this.location = location;
    this.email = email;
    this.time = time;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write a `android.location.Location` object and *that* class doesn't have a public, no-argument constructor. Many Android library classes will not meet the requirements from Firebase, and you'll have to write your own serialization/deserialization to exchange the necessary information with the database.

Also see: [Class android.location.Location does not define a no-argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166657/class-android-location-location-does-not-define-a-no-argument-constructor)